# Contar pulsaciones de " Button" y Mostrar resultado en Html o Php

Tags: javascript, contador

`

```js
      echo '<img src="'.$images[1].'" width=100 height=100 onclick = submit("'.$images[1].'")>';
         ?>
        </td>
        
        <td>
         <?
              echo '<img src="'.$images[2].'" width=100 height=100 onclick = submit("'.$images[2].'")>';
               ?>
        </td>
        
        <td>
         <?
              echo '<img src="'.$images[3].'" width=100 height=100 onclick = submit("'.$images[3].'")>';
         ?>
        </td>
     </tr>
    
    <tr id="fila-2"> etc etc.




<!--------------------recoge nombre de imagenes presionadas y agrega a array----------------------->
   
  <script>
       function submit(nombreImagen) {
          nro = obtenerNumero(nombreImagen);
          numsArray.push(nro);
          console.log(numsArray);
        }
       
       function obtenerNumero(nombreImagen) {
          return nombreImagen.split('.')[0];
        }
  </script>

<!--------------- Compara cantidad de datos en Array y redirecciona o envia por post --------->

<script>
 function hizoClick() {

     if (numsArray.length == 0) { 
          alert("Debes Realizar Tu Selección");
          return;
     }

     if (numsArray.length <5) {
          alert("Debes Elegir 5 Vistas Preferidas");
          return;
     }
```

`Tengo una galeria de imagenes donde cada una tiene su propio "submit", de manera que con solo tocarla ya queda seleccionada y es agregada a un array.
Lo que necesito es que como la seleccion es limitada en número, se muestre en pantalla la cantidad de datos sin importar su nombre, que estan agregadas en el array, leyendo el "numsArray" ( así se llama el array js ) o contando las veces que se apretó un submit, ya que todos los botones aunque seleccionan imagenes distintas, tienen el mismo nombre.
Por Ejemplo Selecciona Las 5 Vistas Mas Lindas( Imagenes De Paisajes Varios ) img 1, img 23, img 100, img 84, img103.      Muestra en html o php   " Has Seleccionado " x Imágenes
Gracias por su tiempo y compartir ideas.

No he probado casi nada porque no encontre información adecuada y lo que encontré, no se aplicaba.
Me interesa que muestre la cantidad de selecciones, lo que sea mas sencillo ya que al fin es lo mismo : o lea cantidad de datos en el array, sin importar sus nombres, solo la cantidad o veces que se hizo click en la pantalla o con el mouse, ya que cada ves que se presiona un submit, se elige una img sin importar cual sea. que muestre un numero en pantalla equivalente a la cantidad de imagen seleccionadas. solo eso.

Comment: Hola, que has intentado? Por favor edita tu pregunta y pon el código que has intentando, un ejemplo del resultado que quieres, etc. Será más fácil que respondan a tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Hola, expliqué un poco mas de lo que necesito por si no se entendió bien, y puse algo de código de muestra, no todo porque es redundante solo una muestra lo más importante resumido.gracias por tu ayuda.